# TexWorks has stopped working for only one tex document

Tags: miktex, texworks

I searched far and wide for a solution to this, but the one topic that could have procured an answer was closed (which didn't make sense to me?).

I have a .tex document in TexWorks that was installed with MikTex that, after trying to input a jpeg figure, made TexWorks crash and stop working. So I commented out the lines to insert the figure, but still every time I try to compile the document, TexWorks crashes. When I compile any other .tex document, however, it works and has no issue.

After trying to find out the issue I typed pdflatex -v in my terminal and received the error: Sorry, but pdflatex did not succeed. 
It then showed me a log file that I could check, and after doing so the error message I received was:

```
    2016-06-22 10:45:22,556-0400 FATAL pdflatex - The command line options could not be processed.
    2016-06-22 10:45:22,557-0400 FATAL pdflatex - Info: optionError="unknown option"
    2016-06-22 10:45:22,557-0400 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\webapp.cpp
    2016-06-22 10:45:22,557-0400 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 270
```

Comment: Did you clear all auxilliary files before compiling again ? It may help.

Comment: Do you have a program directive near the top of the file?

Comment: I did, but clearing the aux file before compiling cleared up the issue.

Comment: I had the same problem.  In case others find it useful: in order to resolve the issue, I had to delete _all_ auxiliary files, not just the ones listed in the "Remove Aux Files" dialogue box.

Comment: Andrew Uzzell's comment solved my problem. I am using TeXworks, and compilation was failing even though I was using exactly the same .tex and .bib files that used to work with no problem. The error message was incomprehensible ("Illegal parameter number in definition of Hy@tempa"). I solved the problem by deleting not just the five files listed when you click Remove Aux Files, but also the .bbl file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in the comments.